# I have a code snippet that adds to counter if condition is true. How can I shorten it?

Tags: python

I am extracting all the external links from a wikipedia page and counting them this way :

```
count = 0 
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    try:
        
        if "wikilink" in a["rel"][0].lower():
            count = count + 1
        
    except:
        pass
print(count)
```

I have simply created a count variable and gets all a tags and if the condition is true it simply adds up. How do I make this code concise the Pythonic way?

Comment: you can remove the `except: pass`, thats one of the least pythonic things you could write

Comment: @Sayse I think they're using that to ignore the elements with no `rel` attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `sum()` function.

```
links = soup.select('a[href][rel]')
count = sum("wikilink" in a["rel"][0].lower() for a in links))
```

The selector will only return anchors that have `rel` attirubtes, so you shouldn't need the `try/except` to skip the ones that don't.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this would be considered more pythonic, but you could perform this counting using a generator expression within `sum`

```
count = sum(1 for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True) if "wikilink" in a.get("rel", [''])[0].lower())
```

Answer (score 0):

I might write something like:

```
print(sum(
    "wikilink" in a.get("rel", "null")[0].lower()
    for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True)
))
```

using `"null"` here as a dummy value that will allow the `[0].lower()` to run without raising and without incrementing the sum (I'm assuming that it's not possible for `a.get("rel")` to return something like an `int` that's not indexable).

Answer (score 0):

This would be more pythonic, but this long expression becomes less readable:

```py
sum(1 for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True) if isinstance(a.get("rel"), list) and len(a.get("rel")) > 0 and "wikilink" in a.get("rel")[0].lower())
```

Checking `isinstance(a.get("rel"), list) and len(a.get("rel")) > 0` makes sure there won't be an exception, so you don't have to wrap it in `try/except`.

To increase readability, I'd split it in two lines:

```py
check = lambda a: isinstance(a.get("rel"), list) and len(a.get("rel")) > 0 and "wikilink" in a.get("rel")[0].lower()
count = sum(1 for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True) if check(a))
```